# Can I set up event dispatching within a console app? If so how?

Tags: .net, winforms, com

I have third party API which seems to depends internally on Windows event dispatching. So it does not work in a console app or windows service.

Can I set up event dispatching within a console app or windows-service? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at `Application.Run()` ... but i can't tell you if this works with services ...

Comment: I do not want to run a Frame in Console application.

Comment: It seems that there is no simple way. So i just add a hidden form to console application to execute the API in that forms.[ run form in Application.Run(hiddenForm) ] .Too ugly method but worked. And also i wrap my api as a dll project which use hidden forms to execute api then able to use it in windows service.

Comment: But hope there will be more elegant way.

Comment: @6.45.Vapuru maybe you want to have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx